# How to get Operational Attrs with Spring Ldap Authorization

Tags: java, spring, spring-ldap

I'm having difficulties to read some operational attrs from user data coming with ldap authentication in spring. I know there's already bunch of Q&As about this subject but none of em really helped me. What I need is to get `isMemberOf` attrs. Our company LDAP admin says '*isMemberOf is an operational attr so it doesnt come with the regular ones from the ldap authentication response. Therefore you need to request them by name*' and he gave me this shell command he uses for it to give me an idea to get them :

```
-bash-3.2$ ldapsearch -h XXX -p 10389 -b dc=entp,dc=tgc -e -1 -T -D "uid=XXX,ou=SpecialUsers,dc=entp,dc=tgc" -w XXX uid=XXX ismemberof         
dn: uid=XXX,ou=people,o=XXX,dc=entp,dc=tgc
ismemberof: cn=3G01,ou=functionGroups,ou=Groups,dc=entp,dc=tgc
```

Spring versions in my project :

```
<spring.version>3.1.1.RELEASE</spring.version>
<spring.security.version>3.1.0.RELEASE</spring.security.version>
<spring.data.commons.version>1.3.1.RELEASE</spring.data.commons.version>
<spring.ldap.version>1.3.1.RELEASE</spring.ldap.version>
```

`.properties` file that stores ldap configuration :

```
app.ldap.url=ldap://XXX
app.ldap.manager.base=uid=XXX,ou=SpecialUsers,dc=entp,dc=tgc
app.ldap.manager.password=XXX
app.ldap.user.base=dc=entp,dc=tgc
app.ldap.user.filter=(uid={0})
app.ldap.user.role.key=ApplicationProfile
```

Beans definitons for authentication :

```
<beans>
    <s:authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
        <s:authentication-provider ref="ldapAuthProvider" />
    </s:authentication-manager>
    <bean id="contextSource"
        class="org.springframework.security.ldap.DefaultSpringSecurityContextSource">
        <constructor-arg value="${ldap.url}" />
        <property name="userDn" value="${ldap.manager.base}" />
        <property name="password" value="${ldap.manager.password}" />
    </bean>
    <bean id="ldapAuthProvider"
        class="org.springframework.security.ldap.authentication.LdapAuthenticationProvider">
        <constructor-arg ref="bindAuthenticator" />
        <constructor-arg ref="authoritiesPopulator" />
        <property name="userDetailsContextMapper" ref="userDetailsContextMapper" />
    </bean>
    <bean id="bindAuthenticator"
        class="org.springframework.security.ldap.authentication.BindAuthenticator">
         <constructor-arg ref="contextSource" />
         <property name="userSearch" ref="userSearch"/>
    </bean>
    <bean id="userSearch"
        class="org.springframework.security.ldap.search.FilterBasedLdapUserSearch">
                <constructor-arg value="${ldap.user.base}" />
                <constructor-arg value="${ldap.user.filter}" />
                <constructor-arg ref="contextSource" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="authoritiesPopulator"
        class="core.spring.security.ldap.AttributeBasedLDAPAuthoritiesPopulator">
        <constructor-arg value="${ldap.user.role.key}" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="userDetailsContextMapper"
        class="core.spring.security.ldap.CustomUserDetailsContextMapper" />
</beans>
```

And when I debug `getGrantedAuthorities(DirContextOperations userData, String username)` function that populates authorities in my `AttributeBasedLDAPAuthoritiesPopulator` class, `userData` only includes these attrs and no other like `isMemberOf` (XXXs are actually some real data):

```
birthdate=birthdate: 06/28/1983, 
givenname=givenName: Dummy User, 
mobile=mobile: XXX, 
workflowaccess=WorkflowAccess: 0, 
objectclass=objectClass: mdsMVLink, top, person, inetOrgPerson, organizationalPerson, inetUser, inetAdmin, iplanet-am-managed-person, iPlanetPreferences, iplanet-am-user-service, 
mdsmvlinktype=mdsMVLinkType: MV#CV1#A, 
userpassword=userPassword: XXX, 
mdsentityowner=mdsEntityOwner: MV,META, 
ou=ou: XXX, 
applicationprofile=ApplicationProfile: XXX
uid=uid: XXX, 
mail=mail: XXX, 
cn=cn: XXX, 
managername=managerName: XXX, 
manager=manager: uid=XXX,ou=people,o=XXX,dc=entp,dc=tgc, 
employeenumber=employeeNumber: TEST15, 
functionalgroupname=functionalgroupname: dummy-functionalgroupname, 
mdslinktocv=mdsLinkToCV: MV#CV1#uid=DUMMY,ou=Employees, 
status=status: 1, 
mdsmvmembership=mdsMVMembership: CV1#True, 
inetuserstatus=inetUserStatus: Active, 
description=description: XXX, 
sn=sn: for TEA project, 
organization=Organization: XXX
```

So my question is how can I get `isMemberOf` attrs too with these ones?

---

What i've tried so far:

1- Adding another filter in `.properties` to include ismemberof

```
app.ldap.user.filter=(&(uid={0})(ismemberof=*))
```

2- Making `isMemberOf` the keyword for roles

```
app.ldap.user.role.key=isMemberOf
```

3- Tried to get it explicitly from userData in populator class

```
userData.getObjectAttributes("isMemberOf")
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the attribute `ismemberof` to the requested attributes of your `userSearch` bean:

```
<bean id="userSearch"
     class="org.springframework.security.ldap.search.FilterBasedLdapUserSearch">
        <constructor-arg value="${ldap.user.base}" />
        <constructor-arg value="${ldap.user.filter}" />
        <constructor-arg ref="contextSource" />
        <property name="returningAttributes">
            <list>
                <value>*</value>
                <value>ismemberof</value>
            </list>
        </property>
</bean>
```

You need to specify both values (`*` and `ismemberof`) because of the behaviour of ldap server:

- if you don't specify attribute names, it will return all user attributes
- if you specify attribute names, it will return exactly those attribute (whether user attribute or operational attribute)
- if you want all user attributes and some operational attributes, you specify `*` for all user attributes and list all the operational attributes you want

Comment: Thank you for the answer but no luck. Even when I remove `<value>*</value>` and use only `<value>ismemberof</value>`, it's still returning only the basic attrs